# When are two groups $\mathbb{Z} + \alpha \mathbb{Z} + \alpha^2\mathbb{Z}$ equal?

Tags: nt.number-theory

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are irrational, and $$\mathbb{Z} + \alpha \mathbb{Z} + \alpha^2\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z} + \beta \mathbb{Z} + \beta^2 \mathbb{Z}$$ does it follow that one of $\alpha + \beta$ or $\alpha - \beta$ is an integer?

For motivation, notice that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are irrational, and $\mathbb{Z} + \alpha\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z} + \beta\mathbb{Z}$, then one of $\alpha + \beta$ or $\alpha - \beta$ is an integer.  Indeed, with these assumptions, we have $\alpha = m + n\beta$ and $\beta = p + q\alpha$ for some integers $m,n,p,q$.  But then $\alpha = m + n(p + q\alpha)$, which implies $nq = 1$, since $\alpha$ is irrational.  Then $n = \pm 1$, so $\alpha = m \pm \beta$.

Comment: No. Counterexample: $\alpha^3=\alpha+1$ and $\beta=\alpha^2$. Pretty much works with any cubic algebraic integer.

Comment: It's not quite *that* easy; **Felipe Voloch**'s example is correct,
but for most cubic algebraic integers $\alpha$ we do not expect any
$\beta \notin {\bf Z} \pm \alpha$ such that ${\bf Z}[\beta] = {\bf Z}[\alpha]$.